# Вывести данные с json на Php

Tags: json, php

Есть json конфиг [cсылка](https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/clan/list/?application_id=1bcefd70abd2992986b16717c8d6d714&search=aces&limit=10)

Как с него вывести названия всех кланов, то есть  "name": "Aces", и т.д.

Comment: @innot, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. @innot, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 3):

```
$obj = json_decode($str);
foreach($obj->data as $v){
   echo $v->name . "\n";
}
```

Код на [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/yx9FpP)